# How to make store to get data using stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures

I have file XML here:

```
<Setup>
  <Include Type="Product">
    <Value uomid="8078">469700_3:9000;2:10000;</Value>
  </Include>  
</Setup>
```

And this is my store to get data:

```
PromotionSetup.query(''
for $PS in Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Product'''']/Value[text()]
where contains($PS, ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '_'''') or $PS = ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '''''
return data($PS)         
'')).value(''(.)'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as InfoProductPromotion
```

This store just receive one parameter, that mean is: 469700.
So. I got an ordeal that set two parameter: one is ProductID: 469700 and the second is: uomid : 8078. And the result will be 469700_3:9000;2:10000;.
So can someone help me to make a store procedure to get data with 2 parameters.

Comment: Stored procedures are too often not ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: XML file was actually a column in database and i'm using store procedure to get data.

Comment: Yes, but if you get an ANSI SQL compliant answer it will probably not help you at all. That's why I asked you to specify dbms product!

Comment: sorry about my english skill!!! That is MSSQL server

Answer (score 0):

My problem is sovled:

```
PromotionSetup.query(''
for $PS in Setup/Include[@Type = ''''Product'''']/Value[@uomid='''''+CAST(@uomID as nvarchar)+'''''][text()]                                        
where contains($PS, ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '_'''') or $PS = ''''' + CAST(@productID AS NVARCHAR) + '''''
return data($PS)'')).value(''(.)'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as InfoProductPromotion
```